# Bag implementation as array in Java

Tags: java, collections, bag

I'm supposed to implement a bag data structure (also called a multiset), an unordered
collection of homogeneous values (any Java object, excluding null) that may have duplicates, for a project. I've done extensive searching on the internet but have a hard time wrapping my mind around using arrays instead of something like List and don't quite understand the syntax for using arrays in a class.

I need to implement all of java.util.Collection except as noted by throwing an UnsupportedOperationException. Yes, I HAVE to use an array and when I add to it, the capacity must increase by 10. My problem is that I'm not sure what to do about the *contains* method, *clear* method, *addAll* method, and a second *constructor*. Hopefully everything else I've added will also run smoothly. I've included the API definition in comment blocks. Any input at all would really help me.

As Mark asked below, I don't understand how to search through the bag to search for a particular element.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;

class Bag<T> implements Collection<T>{
private T[] array;
public int bagSize;


public Bag(){
    array=(T[])new Object[10];
}
public Bag(Collection<T> other ){
    //Not sure what to put here
    //creates a bag containing all of the items passed to it as a Collection<T>
}

public int size() {
    return bagSize; 
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    if(size()==0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


public boolean contains(Object o) {
    //Not sure what to put here
    /*Returns true if this collection contains the specified element. More formally,
    returns true if and only if this collection contains at least one element e such 
    that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)). */
    return (o.toArray()==null ? this.toArray()==null : o.toArray() == this.toArray());
    }

}


public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented.");
}

public Object[] toArray() {
    return array;

}

public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented.");
}

public boolean add(T e) {
   if(bagSize>=array.length)
       return false;
   else
   {
       ensureCapacity(bagSize+10);
       array[bagSize]=e;
       bagSize++;
       return true;
   }

}

public boolean remove(Object o) {
    for(int i=0; i<bagSize; i++)
        if(array[i].equals(o)){
            for(int j=i; j<bagSize-1; j++)
                array[j]=array[j+1];
            bagSize--;
            return true;
        }
    return false;

}

public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented.");
}

public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> c) {
    //Not sure what to put here
    /*Adds all of the elements in the specified collection to this collection  
    (optional operation). The behavior of this operation is undefined if the specified
    collection is modified while the operation is in progress. (This implies that the
    behavior of this call is undefined if the specified collection is this collection,
    and this collection is nonempty.) */
}

public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented.");
}

public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented.");
}

public void clear() {
    //Not sure what to put here
    /*Removes all of the elements from this collection (optional operation). The
    collection will be empty after this call returns (unless it throws an exception).*/
}

@Override
public int hashCode(){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("not implemented.");
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object e) {
    if (e == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != e.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    final Bag<T> other = (Bag<T>) e;
    return true;
}

public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity){
    T[] biggerArray;
    if(array.length<minCapacity){
        biggerArray=(T[]) new Object[minCapacity];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, biggerArray, 0, bagSize);
        array=biggerArray; 
    }
}
```

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083495/bag-data-structure-multiset-class-implemenation-in-java-using-fixed-array

Comment: What's the difficulty? Do you not understand how to iterate through your bag to search for a particular element?

Comment: Yeah, that's part of it...I'm not sure how to iterate through other object arrays, for example, for the contains method.

Comment: @user481211: I think you're somehow misunderstanding the function of the `contains` method. It's given an `Object` (which could be absolutely anything, including `null`) and checks if _this collection_ (this instance of your Bag) contains that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm confused about what you have inside `contains`... you're calling `toArray()` on an `Object`, which doesn't have a `toArray()` method. This suggests some fundamental misunderstanding of what you're trying to do. Despite that, you actually do seem to know how to check if the collection contains a given object, because you have to find the object in order to `remove` it. Your `remove` method returns the exact same `boolean` value that `contains` would have if called with the same object. I think you can work from that.

(Your `remove` method has a bug that could cause a memory leak, by the way... when it shifts the objects in the array to the left by 1, it doesn't set the array slot that is no longer included in the collection to `null`.)

`addAll` is quite simple... you're given a `Collection` of elements that all need to be added, and you have an `add` method that can add an element. These go together. (`addAll` is all you really need to implement your second constructor as well.)

`clear` is also simple. After calling it, your array needs to have no references to any objects and the size of your bag needs to be 0. Just think about how you can do that.

A working implementation of `iterator()` would help you quite a bit as many `Collection` methods (including `clear`) can be implemented by making use of the collection's `Iterator` (the convenient abstract class `AbstractCollection` does this), but implementing that is a bit more difficult than just implementing a basic `clear` that doesn't use it probably.

Also, a small note.

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
    if(size()==0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

would be better written as:

```
public boolean isEmpty() {
  return size() == 0;
}
```

Since `size() == 0` is already a `boolean` expression, the `if`/`else` is redundant.

Comment: I would suggest using the public variable here like `return bagSize == 0;` to check in `isEmpty()` function rather than invoking the function of `size()`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I actually thought about it a little more last night and came to similar conclusions, but thanks for making it all clear, and for correcting my redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the guava's Multiset implementation as a reference. That will give you some idea
http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/com/google/common/collect/

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't help me because I already understand what each method is supposed to do.

Comment: updated the link. u can find the class that implements multiset

Comment: I don't think any of Guava's multisets are implemented directly on top of an array. They're all implemented on top of Maps, so I'm not sure how useful they would be here.